# storing passed variables into array automatically - java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am having trouble storing a variable passed from a class into another classe's array.

I am passing a double that has been scanned in class `A`, to class `B` where I wish for the doubles to be stored in a double array, as long as the scanner in class `A` `hasNext()`.

My code in class `B`, resembles something like this:

```
// I can't seem to get the passed doubles to be stored as individual elements of the array

public class B {

public final static int MAX_SIZE = 200;

public int i;
public double passedOne;

public void store() {


    double[] storedOneVars = storedOneVars[MAX_SIZE]; // create a system to store variables in the array

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        storedOneVars[i] = passedOne;
    }

    for (double s : storedOneVars) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new NumberRow().store();
}

}
```

I am open to suggestions :D

Comment: what is the point of the code?

Comment: @ErikAllik I think the OP is learning how to pass variables. I think that is the point

Comment: variables are not passed; values are.

Comment: Sorry `pass by reference`, but you know what I meant :)

Comment: Sorry for my lack in programming terms, still quite new to this, the point is to build a sort of "database" (double array) in my class B, so I can later retrieve it, from a class later.

Answer (score 0):

My Java is a little rusty, but I don't see where you are passing variable references to your class `B`. To add a reference to a value you can either create a constructor which excepts a parameter or pass the parameter into your `store()` method.

Also, you are instantiating your array incorrectly.

`double[] storedOneVars = storedOneVars[MAX_SIZE];`

should be

`double[] storedOneVars = new double[MAX_SIZE];`

You are also instantiating `NumberRow` but not assigning to a reference variable. Even worse is there is no `NumberRow` class. There is a class `B`. so is should be something like this:

`B myB = new B();`

Here is an example:

```
class B {


    private double[] myDoubleArray;

    public double[] getMyDoubleArray() {
        return myDoubleArray;
    }


    public void setMyDoubleArray(double[] myDoubleArray) {
        this.myDoubleArray = myDoubleArray;
    }

    public B(double[] dArray){

        setMyDoubleArray(dArray);

    }


    public void store() {

        for (double s : getMyDoubleArray()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }   
    }
}

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double[] myd = new double[]{1,2,3};

        B myB = new B(myd);
        myB.store();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit sloppy, origninaly my class name was NumberRow. However, to simplify my question I just called it class B, and forgot to modify some parts of my code.. I pass the variable into this class B, with this in my class A:

Comment: B b = new B();
b.columnOneNewVar = doubleScanner.nextDouble();

Comment: Also I am passing not passing an array, into class B, single a double at a time

Comment: I think I've given you enough to go on. You should be able to figure out the rest. This is very basic java programming.

Comment: Well honestly not really, your code does not seem to add a single (passed) value of a variable at a time to an array.. Which was the problem I was trying to solve. Although I appreciate your good intentions of trying to help me.

Comment: Your original post is so riddled with errors, it will not compile. You should take a look at my answer and see how it works. It might give you a clue on how to solve your problem.